# Как в Redux сохранить полученные данные в store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

Как сохранить данные в store? Только начинаю разбираться в redux не совсем понятно как передать экшен в компонент

фрагмент кода:

```
    // TablePlugin.js
    import React from "react";
    import ReactTable from "react-table";
    import axios from "axios";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import "react-table/react-table.css";
    import { itemsFetchData } from "../actions/action";

    class TablePagin extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          posts: [],
          firstColumnSelected: true
        };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        // axios
        //   .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments")
        //   .then(response => response.data)
        //   .then(data => {
        //     this.setState({ posts: data });
        //   });

        this.props.fetchData(
          "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments"
        );
      }

      handleInputChange(value) {
        this.setState({ firstColumnSelected: !this.state.firstColumnSelected });
      }

      render() {
        const { firstColumnSelected } = this.state;
        const columns = [
          {
            columns: [
              {
                Header: "Post ID",
                accessor: "postId",
                show: firstColumnSelected
              },
              {
                Header: "ID",
                accessor: "id"
              },
              {
                Header: "Name",
                accessor: "name"
              },
              {
                Header: "Email",
                accessor: "email"
              },
              {
                Header: "Body",
                accessor: "body"
              }
            ]
          }
        ];

        if (this.props.hasErrored) {
          return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
        }

        if (this.props.isLoading) {
          return <p>Loading…</p>;
        }

        return (
          <div>
            <div>
              <input
                name="firstColumn"
                type="checkbox"
                checked={this.state.firstColumnSelected}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(this)}
              />
              <label>Скрыть первую колонку</label>
            </div>
            <ReactTable columns={columns} data={this.state.posts} />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = state => {
      return {
        posts: state.posts,
        hasErrored: state.itemsHasErrored,
        isLoading: state.itemsIsLoading
      };
    };

    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
      return {
        fetchData: url => dispatch(itemsFetchData(url))
      };
    };

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps
    )(TablePagin);
// actions/action.js
// import axios from "axios";

// export const fetchSomething = someData => {
//   return dispatch =>
//     axios
//       .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments", someData)
//       .then(response => {
//         dispatch({ type: "LOAD_DATA", payload: response.data });
//       })
//       .then(data => {
//         this.setState({ posts: data });
//       });
// };

import axios from "axios";

export function itemsHasErrored(bool) {
  return {
    type: "ITEMS_HAS_ERRORED",
    hasErrored: bool
  };
}

export function itemsIsLoading(bool) {
  return {
    type: "ITEMS_IS_LOADING",
    isLoading: bool
  };
}

export function itemsFetchDataSuccess(posts) {
  return {
    type: "ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS",
    posts: []
  };
}

export function itemsFetchData(url) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(itemsIsLoading(true));

    // axios
    //   .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments")
    //   .then(response => response.data)
    //   .then(data => {
    //     this.setState({ posts: data });
    //   });

    // this.props.fetchData(
    //   "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/comments"
    // );

    axios
      .get(url)
      .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw Error(response.statusText);
        }

        dispatch(itemsIsLoading(false));

        return response;
      })
      .then(response => response.data)
      .then(posts => dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(posts)))
      .catch(() => dispatch(itemsHasErrored(true)));
  };
}




    // src/store/configureStore.js

    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
    import thunk from "redux-thunk";

    import rootReducer from "../reducers";

    export default function configureStore(initialState) {
      return createStore(rootReducer, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk));
    }




    // src/actions/action.js

    import axios from "axios";

    export function itemsHasErrored(bool) {
      return {
        type: "ITEMS_HAS_ERRORED",
        hasErrored: bool
      };
    }

    export function itemsIsLoading(bool) {
      return {
        type: "ITEMS_IS_LOADING",
        isLoading: bool
      };
    }

    export function itemsFetchDataSuccess(posts) {
      return {
        type: "ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS",
        posts: []
      };
    }

    export function itemsFetchData(url) {
      return dispatch => {
        dispatch(itemsIsLoading(true));
        axios
          .get(url)
          .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw Error(response.statusText);
            }

            dispatch(itemsIsLoading(false));

            return response;
          })
          .then(response => response.data)
          .then(posts => dispatch(itemsFetchDataSuccess(posts)))
          .catch(() => dispatch(itemsHasErrored(true)));
      };
    }
```

полный пример https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-zjgr2

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-zjgr2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Поправил ваш код, там были некоторые проблемы в `action`, и в самом компоненте.

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните ваш вопрос следующими фрагментами кода:
`src/store/configureStore.js`
`src/actions/action.js`
Они нужны для более полного понимания контекста

Comment: добавил фрагменты из этих файлов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема в функции `itemsFetchData`. Там идет проверка `if (!response.ok)`, но свойства `ok` у объекта response нет, по этому всегда пробрасывается Error. Можно выполнить проверку по коду ответа - `if (response.status !== 200)`.

Далее в экшне `itemsFetchDataSuccess` у вас возвращается пустой массив:

```js
export function itemsFetchDataSuccess(posts) {
  return {
    type: "ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS",
    posts: []
  };
}
```

Меняем его на переданный в функцию аргумент `posts` и все заработает.

```js
export function itemsFetchDataSuccess(posts) {
  return {
    type: "ITEMS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS",
    posts
  };
}
```